# Why does STklos not have the first, word, sentence, butfirst, last etc. functions?

Tags: scheme

I'm currently watching [a Berkley computer science video course](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l28HAzKy0N8&index=1&list=PL67444CD99790F839#t=7m58s) where they make extensive use of the Scheme programming language using the old STk interpreter. In the course, the lecturer describes Scheme as having the following functions: first, word, sentence, butfirst, last and many more others. I installed STklos on my Linux machine due to the fact that STk is no longer maintained, but what really surprised me is that none of those functions were available in STklos. Is that true or am I trippin'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Berkeley CS 61A course uses extra, non-standard Scheme libraries which provide additional functions. The library files are available at ftp://anarres.cs.berkeley.edu/pub/scheme/, and the specific file containing the functions you've described is `simply.scm`.

Reference: https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~bh/ssch27/appendix-running.html